# código compila mas não funciona, apenas finaliza com sucesso

Tags: c, compilação

Bom eu sou novo na linguagem C e resolvi me aventurar no mundo das multithreads, pensei em fazer um programa que achasse numeros primos em um intervalo de 1 a N, e para isso dividiria a tarefa em X threads. Para isso o usuario precisaria passar via commandline o N e a quantidade de threads, com isso escrevi o código abaixo porém ele compila sem erros mas não funciona como esperado, por mais que eu coloque um prinf("teste") no inicio da função main() ele não aparece no console, o que esta acontecendo e onde eu errei?

Estou usando um compilador C online e passando 100 e 32 para N e quantidade de threads respectivamente

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *calculaPrimo(void *limitValue) {
    int primo, j;
    int num = 1;
    int maxValue = limitValue;

    while (num <= maxValue) {
        primo = 1;

        for (j = 2; j < num && primo; j++) {
            if (num % j == 0) {
                primo = 0;
            }
        }
        if (primo == 1) {
            printf("%d ", num);
        }
        num++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void criaThreads(char *args[]) {
    int maxValue = atoi(args[1]);
    int maxThreads = atoi(args[2]);
    printf("%d , %d", maxValue, maxThreads);
    
    long t;
    
    pthread_t threads[maxThreads];
    for (t = 0; t < maxThreads; t++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL,(void * ) calculaPrimo, &maxValue);
    }
    for (t = 0; t < maxThreads; t++) {
        pthread_join(threads[t],NULL);
    }

}


int main(int argc, int argv[]) {
    char *args[] = {argv[0], argv[1], argv[2]};
    criaThreads(args);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Como você está compilando? Qual compilador? Quais os argumentos que você está passando para iniciar a aplicação?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com essas informações

Comment: Um erro que vejo é `char *args[] = {argv[1], argv[2]}`, aqui você pega o segundo e terceiro argumento, se você passa apenas dois, o terceiro é nulo. Neste contexto o correto seria `char *args[] = {argv[0], argv[1]}`. Assegure que seus parâmetros estão corretos em `argv`.

Comment: Arrumei isso porem continuo recebendo umwarning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: @BrunoD. Na verdade o ideal é verificar o `argc` para ver se a quantidade de argumentos é o que você precisa (se chamar o programa sem argumentos, não adianta tentar pegar o `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, etc - em C, isso pode não dar erro, mas gera [comportamento indefinido](/q/173886/112052)). E no `main`, certo é `char *argv[]` e não `int *argv[]`. Enfim, fica a dica que já dei abaixo: como está começando, primeiro estude o básico da linguagem e só depois parta para coisas mais complicadas (como threads e ponteiros)

Answer (score 0):

Prezado, fiz algumas alterações em seu código. Elas estão em [tThread.c](https://gist.github.com/hgfernan/ddd4681a6f7b7ec5f3380833909f4221). Para facilitar, deixei seu original em [tThread_orig.c](https://gist.github.com/hgfernan/cf6d395eeebf20712031de8e67295024), e uma comparação entre as duas versões (vulgo *diff*) em [tThread.c.diff](https://gist.github.com/hgfernan/c8564a48106f7db743c7321472fde382)

Segui o padrão ANSI C, que é mais conhecido e popular. Há outras versões de C, que ainda não estão fartamente documentadas.

Seu código é interessante e tem algumas ideias boas. Parabéns !

Parabéns também por tentar entrar no mundo da programação concorrente, que é ainda mais desafiadora do que a programação convencional.

Contudo, seu código tem um problema fundamental: conforme você comenta, sua ideia é dividir a tarefa de localizar primos entre os vários *threads*. No entanto, sua função `calculaPrimo()` faz trabalho exatamente igual para todos *threads*.

Seria necessário dividir a faixa total para cálculo entre os vários *threads*.

Naturalmente, isso traria a necessidade de comunicação entre os *threads*. Mas isso é problema para uma outra pergunta.

Ainda um ponto relevante é que, se você deseja aumentar o desempenho de um processo, deve tentar limitar o número de *threads* ao número de processadores disponíveis em sua arquitetura. O valor que você disse ter colocado, de 32 *threads*, só faria sentido em uma arquitetura com pelo menos 32 processadores.

Boa sorte e continue trabalhando com coragem.

Comment: Lei a em [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) que **Não Deve** em publicações do site: agradece, cumprimentar, adicionar slogans, assinaturas ou qualquer tipo de deferência.

Comment: Estou o indicando essa [documentação de uso do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5484#5484) que é normalmente aplica a perguntas mas que no caso de sua resposta é valida.

Comment: O Stack Overflow [não é um forum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas-%c3%a9-um-f%c3%b3rum), nós somos um site de [perguntas e respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7256/o-que-%c3%a9-o-stack-overflow). Dê respostas mais impessoais, não deixe uma conversa com o usuário, deixe um conceito para o usuários futuros.